# How do I use IAnnotationTransformer in testNG?

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, testng

How do I use IAnnotationTransformer in testNG?
The code never stepped into the transform function when I debugged. It executed all 3 tests. I use Maven to trigger my tests, this is what I have--

```
public class SomeTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public void before(){

        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.setAnnotationTransformer(new Transformer());
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void test1(){}

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void test2(){}

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void test3(){}
}

public class Transformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod){

        if (true){
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Listeners are not automatically picked up until you have set them up using [serviceloaders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-service-loader).

There are multiple ways to specify a listener, based on need.
If you do not want to apply them to all your tests, you may choose to apply a listener on a single class

eg.

```
@Listeners(Transformer.class)
public class InterceptorTC {

@Test(priority..
```

You can also specify a listener from maven surefire plugin.  Read the using custom listener section [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#)

Other ways to specify listener can be to define it in your [suite xml](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml) and specify your suite xml file in the maven plugin.

.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer {

int retrycount = 0;
 int maxretyrcount =2;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (retrycount<maxretyrcount){
        System.out.println("Retrying test " + result.getName() + " with status "
                + getResultStatusName(result.getStatus()) + " for the " + (retrycount+1) + " time(s).");
        retrycount++;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

 public String getResultStatusName(int status) {
        String resultName = null;
        if(status==1)
            resultName = "SUCCESS";
        if(status==2)
            resultName = "FAILURE";
        if(status==3)
            resultName = "SKIP";
        return resultName;
    }
```

}

// another class
public class RetryListner implements IAnnotationTransformer{

```
@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation arg0, Class arg1, Constructor arg2,Method arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    IRetryAnalyzer analyzer = arg0.getRetryAnalyzer();

    if (analyzer == null)   {
        arg0.setRetryAnalyzer(Retry.class);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation,
               java.lang.Class testClass,
               java.lang.reflect.Constructor testConstructor,
               java.lang.reflect.Method testMethod)

This method will be invoked by TestNG to give you a chance to modify a TestNG annotation read from your test classes. You can change the values you need by calling any of the setters on the ITest interface. Note that only one of the three parameters testClass, testConstructor and testMethod will be non-null.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wanna disable your test method just like @test(enable = false) in your code.

Here's a code snippet that modify the content of @Test annotation at run-time :

```
public class Transformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod){      
       if (testMethod.getName().equals("test1")){
            System.out.println("Disable " + testMethod.getName());
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

When you implement one of TestNG interfaces, you can let TestNG know about it with either of the following ways:

1. Using -listener on the command line.
2. Using  with ant.
3. Using  in your testng.xml file.
4. Using the @Listeners annotation on any of your test classes.
5. Using ServiceLoader.

Let me know if you have any concerns related to this.